# Printing a pointers value

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   int x = 99;
   int *pt1;

   pt1 = &x;

   printf("Value at p1: %d\n", *pt1);
   printf("Address of p1 (with %%p): %p\n", pt1);
   printf("Address of p1 (with %%d): %d\n", pt1);

   return 0;
}
```

What are the downsides/dangers to printer pointer values with `%d` instead of `%p`?

Comment: You might want to pick an answer as the "right" one.

Answer (score 5):

%d displays an integer - there is no need for the size of a pointer to equal the size of an integer.

Comment: I guess on a 64 bit system (Windows 7 64bit or Linux amd64 for instance) the size of int are style 32 bits even if the size of pointers are 64 bits.

Comment: if the size isn't equal and you don't cast then you're lying about the VA_ARGS for the printf, which is undefined behaviour!

Comment: @awoodland, exactly, not only that it is UB, it *will* go wrong if there is another format specifier that comes after the `%d` since the stack will be messed up.

Comment: My comment was originally written because I miss-interpreted the wording of this answer the first time I read it as saying "it's ok even if the sizes are different", which on subsequent reading clearly isn't what was meant.

Answer (score 4):

- sizeof( int * ) need not be equal to sizeof( int )
- the library implementation is free to use a different, more appropriate presentation of the pointer value (e.g. hexadecimal notation).
- %p is simply "the right thing to do". It's what the standard says should be used for pointers, while using %d is misusing the integer specifier.

Imagine what happens when someone refactors your code, and somewhat over-enthusiastically exchanges all "int" with "long" and all "%d" with "%ld"... oops.

Comment: Ok thanks. It was lazy thinking from me and I was lucky that indeed sizeof(int*) == sizeof(int) on our architecture. The automatic hex notation is nice.

Comment: Funny. For me the third bullet point always was the strongest argument. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

If on your system pointers happen not to be the same size as `int`s, you can cause an unlimited amount of screwage. If they happen to be the same size, then you're probably safe. As far as the language standards go, though, passing a pointer and treating it as an integer is allowed to set fire to your computer, send pornographic email to your boss, or cause demons to fly out of your nose. It probably won't do any of those things, but it could conceivably print out misleading values or something.

Don't do this. Use `%p` unless you have a desperate need to treat the address as an integer (note: you probably don't); in that case, *actually cast it to an integer type* so that you aren't abusing the argument-passing mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know on dangers and downsides, but by using the %d notation you lose formatting for pointer like (12 vs 0x000012).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the dangers pointed out in other answers, some compilers (e.g. gcc with format-string warnings turned on) will generate a warning that you're passing a pointer to `%d`, which expects an `int`.