# Strange memory allocation code in C, how it works?

Tags: c, memory-management

How does this code work???

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int *addr = (int*) 0x4888d0;
    *addr = 30;
    printf("%i %p\n", *addr, addr);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This should answer a lot of your questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418728/printing-a-pointers-value

Answer (score 6):

It works by assuming `0x4888d0` is a the address of a writable block of memory of at least `sizeof(int)` bytes that does not interfere with the functionality of `printf` or the C runtime system.

Or rather, it doesn't work, at least not on my system (`Segmentation fault`).

Comment: use: `printf("%p\n", malloc(sizeof(int*)));` and then use the printed address

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing strange in it, however, it seems quite dangerous. What this program is trying to do is to write 30 at a specific location. i.e., the Location whose address is contained in 0x4888d0.

Why this code is written like this and why this particular address, well this is anybody's guess.

Comment: Usually such code is written to play with hardware. For eg. parallel port.

Comment: Yes, I copied it from somewhere where the writer was taking about hardware access.

Answer (score 0):

`int *addr = (int*) 0x4888d0;` will give addr an address `=0x4888d0`. This address might be a valid address. But there is no guarantee that it will always work.

Answer (score 0):

As stated above this tends to segment value, or corrupt, normal applications. However,

Modern computers tend to have reserved memory addresses that do magic things, like control I/O, set CPU modes, update memory maps, etc. Memory pages with such are "real" addresses not mapped into the virtual memory regular applications get. Such is where the kernel communicates with hardware controllers. The fact that the provided fragment pokes a memory location and then promptly reads it back is typical of asking a controller for some type of status and then getting the status back (any write to a magic word can update the status the controller makes available to the software... the value may not be important).

So, if this code is from kernel space, or if this is in some micro-controller, or other strange system, the magic memory addresses could be available. Another possibility is that a privileged application has requested special virtual memory mapping from the kernel that can also expose magic pages to it.  This can get weird as while the application requested something be mapped to virtual memory location including 0x4888d0, the real memory page  could be quite different (and unavailable to the application).