# Printing pointer to integer causes segmentation fault. Why?

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, printf, dereference

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int *num2=20;
    printf("\n\n\n%d",num2);
}
```

When I run it as it is, it prints `20`. If I use  `*num2` it causes segmentation fault. Why?

Comment: `%p` instead of `%d`.

Comment: Your code won't compile without warnings (e.g. with `gcc -Wall -g yourcode.c -o yourprog`) and you should care about them. Your code has a huge mistake in it (you cannot assign 20 to the pointer `num2` portably).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418728/printing-a-pointers-value?rq=1

Comment: Spend several hours reading a good book on C programming (and pointers!).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Why printing `num` was okay but `*num` resulted in segmentation fault?

When you say, `int *num2=20;`.  It is equivalent to

```
int *num; /* Type:(int*) num is a pointer to an integer and hence holds address of an integer object. */
num = 20; /* Type of the value assigned to num is (int).*/
```

You are assigning `int` to `int *` . You should have received a

```
warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast[enabled by defaut]
```

`num` points to the address '`20`'. You have no idea even if that is a *valid address*.

Hence when you printed just `num` you had no problems. But dereferencing, the address(`20`) is invalid memory read , causes *undefined behaviour* and that resulted in *segmentation fault*.

---

### Solution:

`num` should hold a valid address. Do not take this risk by assigning some random address yourself.

Avoid that risk by either creating an object of type `int` and assign `num` to hold the address of it or just allocate memory for that. Like,

**i):**

```
int var = 20;    /* var is a integer object holding the value 20 */
```

`&` unary operator helps you get the address of the operand. Use `&` with `var` to get its address and since `var` is an integer, store it in an integer pointer. In your case, `num`.

```
int *num = &var; /* num is a pointer to var. Holds the address of var. */
```

**ii):**

```
int *num = malloc(sizeof *num);
*num = 20;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
int *num2 = 20;
printf("%d", *num2);
```

defines a pointer and initializes it with value `20`. To initialize pointer means to assign an address it will point to to it, i.e. when you do `*num2` (dereference the `num2` pointer), you are trying to access `int` stored at address `20`, which causes *undefined behavior* ~ which in this case turns into seg fault.

Try this instead:

```
int num = 20;
int *pNum = &num;
printf("%d", *pNum);
```

this defines a variable `num` and pointer `pNum` that points to variable `num`, when you dereference `pNum`, you are able to retrieve the value stored in `num`.

Comment: When I print like this it prints 20. If I use  *num2 it prints segmentation fault. Why?

Comment: because there is nothing at address 20.

Answer (score 2):

```
 int *num2=20;
```

It's not a pointer to an integer value. It's an invalid initialization.

This is a pointer to an `int`  object whose value is `20`:

```
int *p = &(int) {20};
```

To print the value of the pointer:

```
printf("%p\n", (void *) p);
```

Answer (score 1):

As others pointed out you have a bug in your code. You confuse integer with pointers to integers You probably meant to do something like this:

```
int num2 = 20;
int* pnum2 = &num2;
```

Use `%p` to print value of a pointer:

```
printf("\n\n\n%p",pnum2);
```

Comment: Oh dear, I edited your post instead of mine by a mistake... sorry.

Comment: No problem, the answer is better now ;)

Comment: Can you please revert my changes? I don't see the history of the changes, so can't revert it properly... Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Use `%p` formatting string:

```
printf("\n\n\n%p",num2);
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not the correct approach. This is how you should go about it:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int num1=20;
    int * num2 = &num1;
    printf("Number1=%d At Address=%p",*num2,num2);
}
```

You will get a seg fault on dereferencing `int *num2=20;` like this `*num2`. What this `int *num2=20;` means is that `num2` points to a memory location 20 NOT the address of a location which holds the integer 20.

Comment: When I print like this it prints 20. If I use  *num2 it prints segmentation fault. Why?

Comment: That is because there is no guarantee if the address 20 is available for you to use. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you write "printf("%d", *num);" You are trying to obtain the value stored at the address 20(0x00000014 in hex). Value at address 20 is not accessible or could be junk. So it causes segmentation fault. Now see this code, this will produce the desired result 20 by dereferencing the pointer:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int *num2;
int value=20;
num2=&value;
printf("\n\n\n%d",*num2);
}
```